How can I determine why Azure SpeechToText Webhooks fail?
Using the Azure SpeechToText REST API I have created a webhook that triggers on TranscriptionCompletion events  as shown in the documentation here. e.g.:
POST {endpoint}/speechtotext/v3.2/webhooks

This webhook calls an onward Azure Function. I've written the challenge/response logic and all works as expected.
However sometimes the webhook gets into a failed state and I've found that when this happens they never recover. There is no predictability about when it will fail. I can see the failed state of the webhooks by calling:
GET {endpoint}/speechtotext/v3.2/webhooks

Example response when it hasn't failed:
{
  "values": [
    {
      "displayName": "Transcription web hook",
      "self": "https://uksouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.1/webhooks/a999aaaa-08b1-8888-b6d9-ff102889g2d1",
      "links": {
        "ping": "https://uksouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.1/webhooks/a999aaaa-08b1-8888-b6d9-ff102889g2d1:ping",
        "test": "https://uksouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.1/webhooks/a999aaaa-08b1-8888-b6d9-ff102889g2d1:test"
      },
      "properties": {
        "apiVersion": "v3.2",
        "secret": "rBbbGfFfF99Jk9"
      },
      "webUrl": "https://onwardfunction20241118173130.azurewebsites.net/api/callback",
      "events": {
        "transcriptionCompletion": true
      },
      "createdDateTime": "2024-11-18T12:10:47Z",
      "lastActionDateTime": "2024-11-18T12:10:49Z",
      "status": "Succeeded"
    }
  ]
}

The onward Azure Function logging doesn't seem to contain any information about it.
I'd like to determine why the webhooks fail, ideally with logging, but I can't find a way to enable logging for them specifically.
How can I determine exactly why the webhooks fail?

Enable Azure Diagnostic and Application Insights for your Speech resource and Azure Function to capture detailed logs on webhook failures.

you have to use GET {endpoint}/speechtotext/v3.2-preview.2/webhooks/{id} for get request. id is the identifier of the webhook.

or with GET {endpoint}/speechtotext/v3.2-preview.2/webhooks   what is out of get and post?

@Sampath I've updated the question to include an example response for GET

Using the GET request only determines the failure status
